# why is the agent option not available in node native fetch?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, node-fetch

I have started using the native fetch function recently (node 17+)

I realized today it is lacking a few functionalities from `node-fetch`, e.g. `agent`

Why is that?

Is there are plan to add it?

It is a shame because I needed to add `node-fetch` to my project as a result

see

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#custom-agent
- https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch

Comment: Isn't the entire point of having `fetch()` built into nodejs that it is the identical API as what's in the browser?  There are richer options such as `got()` or `axios()` or `node-fetch()` if you want support for node-specific behaviors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual answer is to why the options you're used to from the `http` module aren't available is that perhaps surprisingly, node's builtin `fetch()` global does not use the HTTP stack provided by the traditional builtin `http`/`https` modules.

Instead, it uses a parallel, from-scratch HTTP stack rewrite called [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici).

Given that `fetch()`'s HTTP stack is entirely separate from the standard HTTP stack, it should not be surprising that the options you can supply to `http.get` et al don't work with `fetch()`.

[undici's docs are available here](https://undici.nodejs.org/).  http `Agent`s are replaced by a `Dispatcher`.  You can pass a custom `Dispatcher` in to `fetch(…, { dispatcher })`, which allows you to customize `fetch`'s HTTP behavior.

Comment: So does this mean that `fetch(url, { dispatcher: agent })` is what we're looking for here? See https://github.com/nodejs/undici/discussions/2167

Comment: That depends on exactly what `agent` is.  If it's a traditional `http.Agent`, no, the [`Dispatcher` API](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/api/Dispatcher) is entirely different than the [`http.Agent` API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpagent), so passing a `http.Agent` to the `dispatcher` option won't work.  If it's a `undici.Agent`, then yes, that's correct.  The `dispatcher` option takes an `undici.Dispatcher`, which is basically an abstract base class; `undici.Agent` inherits from it.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @josh3736 Is it possible to access or use the Dispatcher/Agent classes without installing undici explicitly?

Comment: @joematune: only if you start node with `--expose-internals`, you can `require('internal/deps/undici/undici')`.

Comment: @josh3736 Thanks! It seems they aren't exporting Dispatcher or Agent as of v21 - only the globals. Am I missing some way to access dispatcher?

Answer (score 1):

The native fetch function is Experimental ie not ready for production and very likely has issues.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch

Also jfriend00 point is very valid: "Isn't the entire point of having fetch() built into nodejs that it is the identical API as what's in the browser?"