# Differences between Node standard https and node-fetch when providing a certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-certificates, node-fetch, node-https

ADP's REST API requires that a SSL certificate and private key be sent with every request.

When I use the 'standard, Node.js HTTP(S) module:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const certificate_path = path.resolve('../credentials/certificate.pem')
const private_key_path = path.resolve('../credentials/private.key')

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.adp.com',
    path: '/hr/v2/workers/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;masked=false',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`
    },
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certificate_path, "utf8"),
    key: fs.readFileSync(private_key_path, "utf8"),
};

require('https').get(options, res => {

  let data = [];

  res.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {

    const workers = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(data).toString());

    for(worker of workers.workers) {
      console.log(`Got worker with id: ${worker.associateOID}, name: ${worker.person.legalName.formattedName}`);
    }

  });

}).on('error', err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message);
});
```

The request works as expected:

```bash
$ node ./standard.js
Got worker with id: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP, name: Last, First
```

However, when I use node-fetch:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const certificate_path = path.resolve('../credentials/certificate.pem')
const private_key_path = path.resolve('../credentials/private.key')

const url = 'https://accounts.adp.com/hr/v2/workers/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'

const options = {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json;masked=false',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  },
  agent: new require('https').Agent({
      cert: fs.readFileSync(certificate_path, "utf8"),
      key: fs.readFileSync(private_key_path, "utf8")
  })
}

fetch(url,options)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((body) => {
      console.log(body);
  });
```

I get an error:

```bash
$ node ./fetch.js   
{
  response: {
    responseCode: 401,
    methodCode: 'GET',
    resourceUri: { href: '/hr/v2/workers/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP' },
    serverRequestDateTime: '2023-03-30T14:25:23.351Z',
    applicationCode: {
      code: 401,
      typeCode: 'error',
      message: 'Request did not provide the required two-way TLS certificate'
    },
    client_ip_adddress: 'a.b.c.d',
    'adp-correlationID': '61f76d29-04e1-48b8-be9d-acf459408b2b'
  }
}
```

What am I missing in the second approach?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps surprisingly, node's builtin `fetch()` global does not use the HTTP stack provided by the traditional builtin `http`/`https` modules.

Instead, it uses a parallel, from-scratch HTTP stack rewrite called [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici).

Given that `fetch()`'s HTTP stack is entirely separate from the standard HTTP stack, it should not be surprising that the options you can supply to `http.get` et al don't work with `fetch()`.

Looking at the [docs](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/?id=undicifetchinput-init-promise), it appears you can pass in a custom [`Dispatcher`](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/api/Dispatcher) object, which in turn can customize the [`Client`](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/api/Client) used to connect to the server.  The `Client` can [configure the TLS client certificate](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/docs/best-practices/client-certificate) used in the request.

Unfortunately, at this time, node's bundled undici is not exposed to user code; you can't `require()` it.  I've not done a deep dive into the internals, but you'll likely have to install the [undici package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) in your project in order to access the classes necessary to build a custom `Dispatcher` that can present the client certificate.

Be careful though, the version of undici is statically bundled with node, so it will depend on the installed node release version.  I can imagine strange bugs resulting from the duplication and/or mismatched versions of the builtin and packaged versions of undici.  A future release of node [may](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43187) expose the bundled undici when things are considered stable.

Given the above, at least in the near term, I'd personally stick to using the traditional `http`(`s`) module instead of `fetch()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any import of node-fetch so I assume you're using the new native fetch added to Node18. The new global fetch does not (yet) support agent options.

See [why is the agent option not available in node native fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73817412/901597)

Comment: An addition for clarity: eventually it might support agent options, but right now it's still experimental.